# How can I retrieve a list of all currently open memory mapped files using c#?

Tags: c#, shared-memory

Ideally I need to implement what SysInternal's VMMAP does (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx) in c# to list the memory mapped files.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented that using WMI Windows Management Instrumentation.
It's a library that you can access a lot of thing of OS, hardware, network and so on.

Check it out: [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa393964(v=vs.85).aspx)